# How to configure kubernetes for gateway aggregation pattern?

Tags: rest, kubernetes, gateway

I would like to configure a gateway to aggregate multiple individual requests into a single request as [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/gateway-aggregation). However, my use case allows user to create additional services.

A user submit a request:

```
POST http://gatway_ip/cards/foo
```

The diagram as follows:

```
   +------------------+    +-----------------+     +-----------------+
   |                  |    |                 |     |                 |
   |   transactions   |    |   User info     |     |   dynamic info  |
   |                  |    |                 |     |                 |
   +------------------+    +-----------------+     +-----------------+
          |                         |                       |
          +----------+     +--------+                       |
                     |     |                                |
                     |     |                                |
                +----v-----v---+                            |
                |              |                            |
                |  /cards/foo  <----------------------------+
                |              |
                +--------------+
                       |
                       |
                       |
                       +
                     User
```

User can start/stop dynamic info on demand. The gateway merges json response from various services. For example:

transactions:

```
{"amount": 4000}
```

user info:

```
{ "name": "foo" }
```

dynamic info:

```
{ "wifeName": "bar" }
```

Gateway responses is:

```
{
    "amount": 4000,
    "name": "foo",
    "wifeName": "bar"
}
```

As far as I know:

- The sample solution on Microsoft website defines a fixed backend.
- Kubernetes ingress only allows routing for incoming requests.

Is there any solution for a gateway aggregation with dynamic back-end ?

*Edited*

**Work around 1**

Refer to [NVIDIA configurations](https://github.com/NVIDIA/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/https-nginx/auto-reload-nginx.sh) for nginx auto-reload, we can take advantages of of Kubernetes ConfigMap, the steps as follows:

- Create a `backend.json` configuration  which is loaded by a lua on event `init_by_lua*` (* is block or file)
- Configure ConfigMap to `backend.json` and use inotify for monitor ConfigMap changes
- Provides a API which sends request to Kubernetes ConfigMap API for user to change configuration. Thus, nginx gateway will auto-reload

*However, this [link](https://karlstoney.com/2017/03/09/nginx-lua-scripting-to-reload-config/) claims that inotify will not work because shared storage was a fuse filesystem*